# Change language of Windows 7 Home Premium to French

Tags: windows-7, language

I have a Dell Inspiron 17R (SWITCH) with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit. I want it to be in French rather than English. With Dell, I have received no installation CD, with the exception of Dell drivers.

I know it won't let me work in my language of choice by default. I do not want to pay for an upgrade to a higher version because the Home Premium version is adequate for me.

Is there an unofficial patch in this case?

Comment: Thank random for editing. Much better explained. I expressed myself badly, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but Home Premium does not allow you to work in the language of your choice:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare (last one)

If you do upgrade, here is a link on how to install language support:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/language-packs

Comment: Yes, I already know that! I ask how to do without having to make an upgrade of my system? Is there an unofficial patch in this case?

Comment: @SilverM-A Well, you did not say you knew that, so I could not know that you did not know. There is probably no way around your dilema, unless you can call Dell and pay for a French DVD if they sell it (not a new program, just the media for about $20). The key on your computer would still work for that. The problem is that you would then be in the same situation, but in reverse: No English if you changed your mind. The only other option is to upgrade to Ultimate. There is not going to be some "unofficial patch". Don't kill the messenger.

Comment: I accept this answer for your comment. I call Dell and they send me a  windows 7 home premium cd in french and a french keyboard for free.

Comment: @SilverM-A Congratulations on such a nice outcome. Thank you for marking it.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need the appropriate language pack, which is available for download, but ONLY for Windows 7 Ultimate. There are Windows 7 Multilingual User Interface Packs (MUI), which will be what you need.

> Windows 7 MUIs provide a translated version of most of the user
>   interface. MUIs require a license to be used and are only available in
>   Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise. If you are using Windows
>   7 Enterprise, contact your system administrator for information about
>   installing additional languages.

Until you upgrade, the only workarounds involve modifying system files, which you can use **at your own risk**, as there is no grantee of them working, and could damage your system.